# PHP GMP not found when using from command line?

Tags: php, shell, gmp

When i try to use `php -f file.php` it says :

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function gmp_init() in /file.php:10
```

However when I add the script as a function to my wordpress site, it doesn't give error and works. What can be the problem?

Using php7.1-fpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have few versions of php and only one has GMP installed, you should run a command with php version.

```
php7.1 -f file.php
```

Answer (score 0):

gmp_init() is not loaded whrn you are doing php -f file.php. Add

```
var_dump(function_exists('gmp_init'));
```

at the top of file.php to confirm.

Comment: Maybe, but how do I load it then? It's a library in /etc/php/php7.1/